# CSS linear-gradient displaying wrong color

Tags: html, css, linear-gradients

I'm trying to create a simple horizon striped background use linear-gradient and background-size, the first colour is displaying correctly, but the second colour **#58a** is displaying a **1px overlay mask** in the left side

HTML:

```
<div></div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    height: 100px;
    background: linear-gradient(#fb3 0, #fb3 50px, #58a 0px, #58a 100px);
}
```

Check the result in this link: https://codepen.io/migcoder/pen/BpOGdL

You may have to **zoom-in** the browser to see that **1px overlay mask** clear.

The strange thing is that if I change the second colour to blue or red(probably more other colours), the problem is gone.

I tested this in Chrome, Firefox and Edge, they are all have same issue, is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: Maybe its got something to do with OS, system configs etc, I don't know but even at 200% zoom I don't see what you've highlighted in the screenshot. I am using Chrome on a Win7 PC.

Comment: Chrome and other Browser insert default styling. Maybe this causes the gap. Like Harry, I also cannot see what you exactly mean. Use the inspector to see whats going on.

Comment: Add `body {margin:0}` before div css.

Comment: I cannot see the problem in your screenshot either. Sounds like chromatic aberration. Are you wearing glasses? Have you tried viewing a screenshot at high magnification (without smoothing)?

Comment: typo: color stops should be at 0, 50px, **50px** (not 0) and 100px, isn't it? I can't reproduce the problem either (neither with 0 nor 50px)

Comment: yes I'm wearing glasses and I already tried viewing the screen at high magnification, still same problem.

I also connected to another computer at the remote desktop connection tool, same issue too

But if this is a issue with my monitor, I need to change the device to test it.

I will also try the method that @K3N suggested.

Comment: @FelipeAls, 0 mean that the second color stops will start from 50px, if a color stop postion small than any previous color stops position, it will get the max position from the previous color stops positions. The reason I do this is that I don't want to change the 50px twice.

Comment: @K3N, **body {margin:0}** works! but why? Could you please give me some description?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `body {margin:0}` "works" because it removes the white lit pixel on the left. Lemme dive down deeper -

Each pixel in the monitor is built using vertical LED segments for red, green, blue. Red + green makes the yellow but fills only the first to segments of the pixel, while the blue fills only the last one.

It's easier to see in an illustration -

[image: LED pixel]

This represents a single pixel on the physical screen. The quality and physical separation depends on the quality of the cell as well as the physical size and resolution of the screen. The lower quality and/or lower resolution, the bigger the cell will appear - also optical influences such as glasses etc. will affect how the cells are perceived through things such as chromatic aberration and general distortion.

The white lit cells next to it can amplify the effect via increased contrast. Removing the margin so that the colored areas is next to dark color will reduce the effect. So basically, it's an optical phenomena (I guess you could call it an illusion, however, there is a actual real physical separation on the screen) due to how the pixel cell is built.

You can amplify the effect even further by using only red and blue colors (the result depends of course on the monitor etc. this is being watched):

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(#f00 0, #f00 50px, #00f 0px, #00f 100px);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

If we now take a closer look at the actual *physical screen* showing the result from the code above:

[image: snapshot]

we can see the separation more clearly (the image isn't the best, but hopefully good enough to illustrate; two lines with red, two with blue):

[image: Physical pixel]

The pixels to the left represents white of course, and will, because of contrast make the unlit segment next to it (in this case the blue ones) more obvious and therefor increase the effect.

Comment: Simply awesome. Thanks a lot for your contribution.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your screen-shot does not feature any 1px overlay mask. Here's a magnified version of your own picture:

[image: Magnified screen-shot]

I'm pretty sure it's a mere optical illusion.

Answer (score 0):

Add prefix for navigators

```
div {
  height: 100px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fb3 0, #fb3 50px, #58a 0px, #58a 100px);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fb3 0, #fb3 50px, #58a 0px, #58a 100px);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fb3 0, #fb3 50px, #58a 0px, #58a 100px);
  background: linear-gradient(#fb3 0, #fb3 50px, #58a 0px, #58a 100px);
}
```